# Java swing diffrent layouts on the same component

Tags: java, swing

I've got a bit of a problem. I need to use two diffrent types of layouts on diffrent tabs in JTabbedPane component.Here's the code:

MyPanel.java

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.util.*;

 public class myPanel extends JPanel{
    myPanel(){
        super(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        myYear year = new myYear();
        myDate mydate = new myDate();
        String s_year = Integer.toString(myDate.year);
        tabbedPane.addTab(s_year,year);
        myMonth month = new myMonth();
        tabbedPane.addTab(mydate.getMonth(),month);


        add(tabbedPane);

        tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
    }


 }
```

GridLayout() on year-pane is necessary because it's displaying 4x4 squares (for each month). But when it comes to month-pane I need to use JList component and I want to put it on the "west border". I've tried to do this like :

```
 package Lista8;

 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;

 class myMonth extends JPanel{

    myMonth(){
        String[] data = {"oneone"};
        JList month = new JList(data);
        month.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        month.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL_WRAP);
        month.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        month.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,200));
        add(month,BorderLayout.WEST); // HERE
    }
 }
```

But month-panel keeps stucking in the center. To be honest I don't quite understand how layouts works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
add(month,BorderLayout.WEST); // HERE
```

The default layout manager of a `JPanel` is a `FlowLayout`.

If you want to use a `BorderLayout`, then you need to set the layout of the panel to a `BorderLayout`.

```
myMonth()
{
    setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

    String[] data = {"oneone"};
    ...
```

> To be honest I don't quite understand how layouts works

Start by reading the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). You will find working code for each layout manager you can download and play with to learn the basics.